# Are 2^n and 4^n in the same Big-Θ complexity class?

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

Is 2^n = Θ(4^n)?

I'm pretty sure that 2^n is not in Ω(4^n) thus not in Θ(4^n), but my university tutor says it is. This confused me a lot and I couldn't find a clear answer per Google.

Comment: You've already got quite a few answers, so I guess this should remain, but... A question like this is a *lot* better suited for [CS Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/). SO is more for code and such, not theory. And on CS you have actual scientists :)

Comment: True - as programmers, both are in Θ(don't do that)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`2^n` is **NOT** big-theta (Θ) of `4^n`, this is because `2^n` is **NOT** big-omega (Ω) of `4^n`.

By definition, we have `f(x) = Θ(g(x))` if and only if `f(x) = O(g(x))` and `f(x) = Ω(g(x))`.

#### Claim

`2^n is not Ω(4^n)`

#### Proof

Suppose `2^n = Ω(4^n)`, then by definition of big-omega there exists constants `c > 0` and `n0` such that:

`2^n ≥ c * 4^n` for all `n ≥ n0`

By rearranging the inequality, we have:

`(1/2)^n ≥ c` for all `n ≥ n0`

But notice that as `n → ∞`, the left hand side of the inequality tends to `0`, whereas the right hand side equals `c > 0`. Hence this inequality cannot hold for **all** `n ≥ n0`, so we have a contradiction! Therefore our assumption at the beginning must be wrong, therefore `2^n is not Ω(4^n)`.

#### Update

As mentioned by [Ordous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3489074/ordous), your tutor may refer to the complexity class [EXPTIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME), in that frame of reference, both `2^n` and `4^n` are in the same class. Also note that we have `2^n = 4^(Θ(n))`, which may also be what your tutor meant.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that what the OPs professor *meant* is **likely** `complexity classes` which is **different** to being in the same big-theta. In that frame of reference, both `2^n` and `4^n` are in the same class, namely `exptime`. Just like `n^2` and `n^3` are in `polytime`, even though they are not in big-theta of each other. The motivation for these classes (polynomial reduction) may also be useful.

Comment: Isn't it easier to just say that `4^n = 2^n * 2*n`? Here you see plainly that the two differ by a non-const factor that depends on n.

Comment: My solution gives a **formal mathematical proof** why a non-constant factor *implies* `2^n is not Ω(4^n)`, @ajcr has also described the corresponding argument in plain words in his edit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: one way to see this is to notice `4^n = 2^(2n)`. So `2^n` is the same complexity as `4^n` (exponential) because `n` and `2n` are the same complexity (linear).

In conclusion, the bases don't affect the complexity here; it only matters that the exponents are of the same complexity.

**Edit**: this answer only shows that `4^n` and `2^n` are of the same complexity, not that `2^n` is  big-Theta of `4^n`: you're correct that this is not the case as there is no constant `k` such that `k*n^2 >= n^4` for all `n`. At some point, `n^4` will overtake `k*n^2`. (Acknowledgements to @chiwangc / @Ordous for highlighting the distinction in their answer/comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Both have exponential complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes theta is possible even though big omega did not satisfied but equality exist by using [stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation). hence (2^n)=θ(3^n).