# Is the complexity of 2^n equal to 2^(n/10) asymptotically?

Tags: math

The first one is a big-theta of 2^n, and then also the other is a big-theta of 2^n because there is a constant that divide n.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not equal asymptotically.

You should be able to find constants k<sub>1</sub> and k<sub>2</sub> for functions k<sub>1</sub>*2<sup>n</sup> and k<sub>2</sub>*2<sup>n</sup> that will bound 2<sup>n/10</sup>. We know that 2<sup>n/10</sup> = (2<sup>n</sup>)<sup>(1/10)</sup> which cannot be expressed as c*2<sup>n</sup>.

Comment: Ok, thx a lot. Another quick question: if I had 2^(n+10) instead of the second that I wrote in the question, this time it would be same complexity of 2^n right ?

Comment: Yes, it would be the same because 2^(n+10) = 2^n*2^10 = c*2^n where c = 2^10.

Comment: Small typo: `2^(n/10) = (2^n)^(10)` - RHS should be `(2^n)^(1/10)`

Answer (score 0):

2^(n/10)=(2^(1/10))^n not same as 2^n

See this 
[Are 2^n and 4^n in the same Big-Θ complexity class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119413/are-2n-and-4n-in-the-same-big-%CE%98-complexity-class)

the link explain 2^n and 4^n